# Can AngularJS set the responseType after a response has been received?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular 1.x application that is expecting to receive a binary file download (pdf) using a `$http.post()` call.  The problem is, I'd like to alternatively get a processing error message that's sent as json. I can do this with the config

```
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/pdf, application/json'
}
```

The problem is I have have to set `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`, otherwise the pdf binary is escaped (or altered such that it doesn't load).  However, that prevents the json from being read or interpreted correctly.

How can I have both?

**Edit:** I'm going to try to clarify; perhaps my understanding is incorrect.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/myresource",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/pdf, application/json'
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
.then(
    function(response) {
        // handle pdf download via `new Blob([data])`
    }, function(response) {
        // pop up a message based on response.data
    }
)
```

In a scenario where I return a pdf data block and a http status of 200, the first function handles the response and prompts the user to save the file.  However if the status is an error (422), the `response.data` is undefined.  I assume this is because the `responseType` is preventing the json from being handled correctly.

If I remove the `responseType` line, the error data is correctly read, but when the pdf is saved, some of the file bytes aren't correct and it's effectively corrupted.  I assume this is because the file is being encoded because javascript was expecting a string.

Comment: don't send server errors as success data.  send them as errors.  sending a 200 success with an error message to process only confuses the API consumer.

Comment: @Claies, I am not sending the error as a 200 status (it's a 422).

Comment: @georgeawg, I am setting the corresponding content-type for each response.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType), _If an empty string is set as the value of responseType, it is assumed as type "text"._  So, I expect if I don't set it, it's altering the pdf.  But, if I do set it, it won't properly handle the json result.

Comment: I am really not sure I understand the problem; if your error message is on a different http status, then you wouldn't need to accept it's content-type in the header, unless I am completely wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An XHR `responseType` property can not be changed after a response has been loaded. But an `arraybuffer` can be decoded and parsed depending on `Content-Type`:

```
 var config = {
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    transformResponse: jsonBufferToObject,
  };

  function jsonBufferToObject (data, headersGetter, status) {
      var type = headersGetter("Content-Type");
      if (!type.startsWith("application/json")) {
        return data;
      };
      var decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
      var domString = decoder.decode(data);
      var json = JSON.parse(domString);
      return json;
  };

  $http.get(url, config);
```

The above example sets the XHR to return an `arraybuffer` and uses a `transformResponse` function to detect `Content-Type: application/json` and convert it if necessary.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/68fkZCGJ3CdEhzW0bRz0?p=preview)

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for (didn't understand).

Comment: AngularJS $http uses the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). The [new Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) can do both or change on the fly.