# Multiple response types in a single $http call

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `$http` call that I use to receive a `pdf` file. Note that `responseType` is `arraybuffer`.

```
$http({
        url: "http://localhost:9000/generatepdf",
        method: "POST",
        responseType: "arraybuffer"

    }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.ret != 0) {
                var errorMessage = response.data.msg;
                // display error message     
            }
            else
                downloadFile(response.data);
        });
```

If the `pdf` generation fails I need to display an error message. In that case the response from the server is a plain `json` message, (responseType = `json`).

How to change `responseType` depending on the response?

Comment: did you try not sending the responseType in the request itself? I think the server would automatically send it and you'd get the correct response.

Comment: @ps0604, rather than approach this problem by wanting to vary `responseType`, you can use the `transformResponse` property on the `$http` request to read the `Content-Type` provided by the server and decode accordingly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919572/can-angular-set-the-responsetype-after-a-response-has-been-received